Fixing burnt kitchen countertop
How to fix this countertop?
It was burnt by a hot pot.
I think it some kind of painting.


That's a typical laminate countertop. Commonly called Formica but that is like calling all tissues Kleenex.

it is plastic not stone

It doesnt look like stone. Its a laminate of some kind, such as formica/sunmica etc.
It looks burnt. If that is the case, you have to get it replaced. Get some quotes from benchtop refurbishers.

With the small size of that counter, replacement is probably the best.  A long counter might suggest to add a pot holder or something in it.

That is what is known as a Post-form countertop. They are manufactured in an industrial facility as opposed to a laminated counter that can be made by a cabinet maker or home DIYer.
It cannot be repaired. A sanding of the burn and attempt to cover the area with paint may temporarily provide a slightly better esthetic look. However this removes the top plastic layer and opens the area up to water infiltration. In time the water degrades the wood base and the counter is worse.
Unfortunately the best/ only option is replacement.
